# Getting element by ID in coffeescript

Tags: html, css, coffeescript, sass, dashing

I'm trying to create a HTML widget:

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <h1 class="title" data-bind="title">Title</h1>

    <div>
        <h1 id = "dc1" class="dc">DC1</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1 id = "dc2" class="dc">DC2</h1>
    </div>

    <p class="updated-at" data-bind="updatedAtMessage"></p>
</div>
```

And I need to be able to set the background color of the `id="dc1"` and `id="dc2"` elements dynamically in CoffeeScript. I plan to do this by adding a class with a background color setting:

**SCSS:**

```
&.up {
    background-color: green;
}

&.down {
    background-color: red;
}

.dc {
    background-color: orange;
    font-size: 30px;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
```

So far I have managed to set the whole widget background but not the child elements mentioned above:
I have been using:

**CoffeeScript:**

```
$(@node).removeClass('up down')
$('#dc1').removeClass('up down')
$('#dc2').removeClass('up down')

$(@node).addClass('down')
$('#dc1').addClass('down')
$('#dc2').addClass('up')
```

*Note ultimately I will add the classes depending on some data rather than hard coding them to 'up' or 'down' in the coffeescript.*

But nothing happends.. Am I getting selecting the `id="dc#"` elements correctly?

If it helps with context I'm doing this for [Dashing](http://dashing.io/)

Comment: Isn't in coffescript `$('#dc1').addClass('down')` -> `$("#dc1").addClass "down"`?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your CoffeScript, the issue must be somewhere else

Comment: @Vucko The parentheses are often *optional* in CoffeeScript but lots of people (including me) put them in to make the code clearer. Single quotes are also valid for strings in CoffeeScript, double quotes are also valid but they support string interpolation so many people (including me) stick to single quotes unless they specifically want to use interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SCSS doesn't make sense so I'd guess that your missing an error from the SCSS-to-CSS conversion. An `&` in SCSS is a [reference to the parent selector](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#parent-selector):

> `&` will be replaced with the parent selector as it appears in the CSS

so have `&.up` at the top level makes no sense and should generate an error. If we fix the SCSS so that `.up` and `.down` apply only to `.dc`:

```
.dc {
    /* ... */
    &.up {
        background-color: green;
    }
    &.down {
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

then everything seems to work just fine.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/9y9uywm9/

You can use [Sassmeister](http://sassmeister.com) (and other similar online tools) to see what SCSS thinks of your original SCSS.

Comment: Thanks I would never have noticed that, do you know of any good scss validators I could use that would have pointed that out?

Comment: I'd think that any SCSS to CSS converter would complain about errors. There are some tools listed on http://sass-lang.com/install